# How to select all items for a particular dimension in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Is there a more efficient way to select items from a `raw_list` to achieve this

`new_list = [raw_list[0][2], raw_list[1][2], raw_list[2][2]]`

I was trying to do something like `raw_list[:][2]`, but `:` could not do what I want.

Comment: `[el[2] for el in raw_list[:3]]` ? (or just `[el[2] for el in raw_list]` if you want the 3rd element of every list in `raw_list`)

Comment: Can I ask what is el?

Comment: Just the name of the variable for the list-comp... `for el...` you can change `el` to whatever you want - just something I tend to use... you might want to have a goosey at https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: yes, can you please write it to the answer?

Comment: It's been answered several times before - so it's not of much benefit answering it again... I've linked this post to a fairly decent question/answer though

Comment: sure, you have closed it.

Answer (score 1):

it is as simple as looping through the list and getting the item at the position 0:

```
alist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
newList = []
x=0
while x != len(alist):
    print(alist[x][0])
    newList.append(alist[x][0])
    x = x + 1
```

This can be done a little more effectively with a for loop, and i suggest you use that, but a while loop is more explanatory.

Comment: Not really, I want the sub-item from all the parent groups.

Comment: oh, let me edit it for that, i didn't understand

Comment: I think it is still not the case. The list should be evenly nested.

Comment: Jon Clements already solved it

Comment: Jon Clements's way is much easier.

Comment: Then use that method! :D